# React initial state: 2 Radio Buttons in each row of a Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have a table with 2 radio buttons in each row to either approve or reject the row. The onChange event saves the ID of each row and if it was approved or rejected. There is then a button to save this in the back end.

That all works fine.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Button } from 'reactstrap';

    class ApproveDataList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            changedValues : {}
        };
    }

    onChange = (selectedIndex, e) => {
        var changedValues = Object.assign({}, this.state.changedValues);
        changedValues[selectedIndex] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ changedValues });
    }

    save(e) {
        //save this.state.changedValues
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Approve</th>
                        <th>Reject</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.approveData.map((approveData) =>
                    <tr >
                        <td>{approveData.signoffId}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <input 
                                type="radio" 
                                value={"approve" + approveData.signoffId} 
                                name={"radio" + approveData.signoffId} 
                                onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, approveData.signoffId)} />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <input 
                                type="radio" 
                                value={"reject" + approveData.signoffId} 
                                name={"radio" + approveData.signoffId} 
                                onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, approveData.signoffId)} />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <Button  onClick={this.save.bind(this)} >Save</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ApproveDataList
```

I'm now confused on how to set the initial state of the radio buttons when I load this component from the back end.

My gut feeling was to do

```
... value={"approve" + approveData.signoffId}  checked={approveData.signedOff}
```

and

```
... value={"reject" + approveData.signoffId} checked={!approveData.signedOff}
```

But of course this won't work. I think I need to store the initial values in State and use that but not sure how to do this as I'm new to React and haven't found a specific solution online.

Please help!

Comment: [check](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs) if this helps. If not, i will try to post answer.

Comment: Thanks but not what i'm looking for. That example just uses a static radio button group. I have a dynamic amount of radio button groups depending on the count of this.props.approveData

Comment: on initial load, which radio button you want to show as selected?

Comment: if {approveData.signedOff} is True I want the radio button with value={"approve" + approveData.signoffId}  to be selected ... and if it's False I want the other one to be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate your issue with small code of my own.

```
const dataArray = new Array(15).fill(null).map((_, index) => ({
  signoffId: index,
  signedOff: Math.random() < 0.5,
}));

export default function App() {
  return dataArray.map((obj) => (
    <div>
      <label style={{ margin: '1rem' }}>
        <input
          type="radio"
          value={'approve' + obj.signoffId}
          name={'radio' + obj.signoffId}
          defaultChecked={obj.signedOff}
          onChange={onChange.bind(this, obj.signoffId)}
        />
        Approve {obj.signoffId}
      </label>
      <label style={{ margin: '1rem' }}>
        <input
          type="radio"
          value={'reject' + obj.signoffId}
          name={'radio' + obj.signoffId}
          defaultChecked={!obj.signedOff}
          onChange={onChange.bind(this, obj.signoffId)}
        />
        Reject {obj.signoffId}
      </label>
    </div>
  ));

  function onChange(selectedIndex: number, e: React.BaseSyntheticEvent) {
    console.log(selectedIndex, e.target.value);
  }
}
```

I used functional React component but the workings should be same.

you need to set `defaultChecked` prop on your radio button for initial state. If you want to set `checked` prop then you need to change `signedOff` property of respective object in `onChange` handler.